Showing there exists one element orbit
Let $G$ be a p-subgroup in $GL_n(K)$ where $K = \mathbb{Z}_p$. Show that there exists $v_0\in K^n$ such that for each $g\in G$ we have $g(v_0) = v_0$.
I'm familiar with the notion of orbits and group actions and see that $G$ acts on $K^n$ and that I need to show that one orbit has one element, but don't see how to get this result.

I suppose that $K$ the finite field $\Bbb F_p$? Usually, $\Bbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.
